# Append Data to jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'd like to append data to jqgrid so when the user hits See more button, it loads additional data retrieved via JSON request.

**Html**

```
  <div id="SeeMoreSearchResultsDiv" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="ancSearchResultsSeeMore" class="grayButton" style="float: left; left: 350px;">            <ul> 
                <li class="ltImg"></li> 
               <li><a href="#" onclick="seeMoreFunction()">See more</a></li>
                   <li class="rtImg"></li> 
                  </ul> </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my Grid

```
   jQuery("#SearchResultDataGrid").jqGrid({
url: updatedURL,
datatype: "json",
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
jsonReader: {
    id: "CTSID",
    cell: "",
    root: function (obj) { return obj.Results; },
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return obj.Count; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
    repeatitems: false
},
colNames: ['CTS ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Type', 'Status', 'Platinum ID', 'RSM Group Code'],
colModel: [{ name: 'CTSID', index: 'CTSID', width: 40, align: "center" },{ name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', width: 150, align: "center" }, { name: 'CityAndState', index: 'CityAndState', width: 90, align: "center" }, { name: 'CustomerTypeName', index: 'CustomerTypeName', width: 50, align: "center" }, { name: 'CustomerStatusName', index: 'CustomerStatusName', width: 50, align: "center" }, { name: 'PlatinumID', index: 'PlatinumID', width: 50, align: "center" },{ name: 'RSMGroupCode', index: 'RSMGroupCode', width: 100, align: "center" }],
pager: false,
rowNum: -1,
//  rowList:[25,50,75,100],
sortorder: "asc",
autowidth: true,
viewrecords: true,
shrinkToFit: true,
rownumbers: false,
clearGridriData: false,
gridview: true,
caption: false});
```

and here's how I'm calling it

```
 function seeMoreFunction() { 
         page = page + 1; updatedURL = updateSearchString(" "); refreshGrid();
        }
     function refreshGrid() 
      { $('#SearchResultDataGrid').setGridParam({ url: null });    $('#SearchResultDataGrid').setGridParam({ url: updatedURL }); $('#SearchResultDataGrid').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
}
```

I verified JSON requests and they are correct but the problem is I'm not able to append to existing data. I've disabled clearGridData.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is "See More" button and associated code?

Comment: Here's seee More button 
<div id="SeeMoreSearchResultsDiv" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="ancSearchResultsSeeMore" class="grayButton" style="float: left; left: 350px;">
            <ul>
                <li class="ltImg"></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="seeMoreFunction()">See more</a></li>
                <li class="rtImg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: and here's seeMoreFunction()
`code`
 function seeMoreFunction() {
        page = page + 1;
        updatedURL = updateSearchString(" ");
        refreshGrid();
    }

 function refreshGrid() {
        $('#SearchResultDataGrid').setGridParam({ url: null });
        $('#SearchResultDataGrid').setGridParam({ url: updatedURL });
        $('#SearchResultDataGrid').trigger('reloadGrid');
    }

Comment: Don't add code in comments. You can edit your original question.